# Using a webservice from my Zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working with an external API webservice that returns a json output true or false. I visit a URL like

```
http://site.com/api/valid
```

and it gives me something like this, which looks like json

```
"true"
```

Right now I'm visiting the url manually, but I want to now do it programmatically from within my zend project. What should I use to get the result correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of ways. The simplest is to use `file_get_contents()`.

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://site.com/api/valid");
// if result is truly json
// data will be 
//    array( 0 => true)
$data = json_decode($result);
```

If it is a popular webservice . there might be a library written for it already. This is preferred since it will handle error conditions and corner cases. [Google](http://framework.zend.com/download/overview) around for it first.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a method that can grab the endpoint. Well, there's many ways but since you are already using Zend, you might as well read up on http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html

Here's a static method:

```
    static function curl($url, $method, $params = array()){
            $client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
            if($method == "POST"){
                $client->setParameterPOST($params);
            }else{
                $client->setParameterGet($params);
            }
            $response = $client->request($method);
            return $response->getBody();
        }
```

Or use php's native method $response = file_get_contents($url);

Make sure to json_decode() your responses.